# How to shift up in a 2048 game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list which I already made to look like a 2048 board:

```
nlist = [2, 2, 4, 8, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0]
```

which looks like this for the 2048 game board:

```
2 2 4 8
0 2 8 0
0 0 0 2
4 2 2 0
```

I want to make a shift funtion that will remove all the 0's from each *column* (not row), then put them back so that the 0's are at the bottom and the non zero numbers go to the top so that this board now looks like this when I press the <kbd>w</kbd> key:

```
2 2 4 8
4 2 8 2
0 2 2 0
0 0 0 0
```

I just need to find a way to go through every single line and row with 2 for loops.

Comment: Could you please show us your current effort (piece of code)?

Comment: Have you considered using either a list of row-lists, a list of column-lists, or a 2D array (e.g., using NumPy), instead of a flat list? While it _is_ doable this way, it will be a lot harder to read, and easier to get wrong, because you need to do arithmetic like `nlist[row * width + col]` and the like all over the place.

Comment: Only way for us to help you is when you show us what you've tried so far. Please create a a very compact code snippet has exhibits your problem. Something like: "I want to achieve A, I have tried these code snippets B and C. B fails with this exception & stacktrace and C gives me the wrong answer." At the moment your questions seems as if it is an homework assignment for us.

Comment: Anyway, even if you _want_ to do this with a flat list, you should probably start by writing functions to get and set values by row and column. For example, `def getrc(nlist, width, r, c): return nlist[r*width+c]` and `def setrc(nlist, width, r, c, value): nlist[*width+c] = value`. Then it should be pretty easy to loop over all the values in a column, etc. (You can always try to make it more concise or efficient or whatever _after_ you've got the explicit way working. That way, you have working code you can test against. But probably you won't even want to do that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a read-write loop

```
for col in range(4):
    wp = 0  # write pointer
    for row in range(4): # read loop
        if data[row*4+col] != 0:
            # non-zero: copy this element in place
            data[wp*4+col] = data[row*4+col]
            wp += 1
    # Fill the rest with zeros
    for row in range(wp, 4):
        data[row*4+col] = 0
```

Comment: @J.Doe: That's a different question.

Answer (score 4):

This would be a whole lot easier if you used a 2D NumPy array, or at least a list of row-lists or list of column-lists, instead of a flat list like this.

But, if you want to stick with the flat list, we can make it easier by adding functions to access that list by row and column, so you don't have to write the arithmetic all over the place:

```
def getrc(nlist, width, r, c):
    return nlist[r*width+c]

def setrc(nlist, width, r, c, value):
    nlist[r*width+c] = value
```

Now, getting or setting a whole column is a simple loop:

```
def getc(nlist, size, c):
    return [getrc(nlist, size, r, c) for r in range(size)]

def setc(nlist, size, c, col):
    for r in range(size):
        setrc(nlist, size, r, c, col[r])
```

And now you only have to write a `shift` function that takes a column list:

```
def shift(lst):
    # Get all the nonzero values in the column
    result = [value for value in lst if value]
    # And pad it with zeros
    result.extend(0 for value in lst if not value)
    return result
```

And now you can put it all together:

```
def shiftcolumns(nlist, size):
    for c in range(size):
        col = getc(nlist, size, c)
        col = shift(col)
        setc(nlist, size, c, col)
```

Can you make this more concise, or more efficient? Sure. But would you be able to understand, debug, and extend the code? If not, just keep it simple.

If you really want it to be more efficient—although it's almost certainly not going to matter—you should probably be using NumPy here.

And if you really want it to be concise, you should *again* probably be using NumPy here. And then the code will be not only shorter, but easier to understand and harder to get wrong. (Or, if you're doing this for an exercise to teach yourself how to do 2D indexing, write your *own* 2D array class that does a small subset of what NumPy does, wrapping up those `getrc`, `setrc`, `getc`, etc. functions in a `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
nlist = [2, 2, 4, 8, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0]
size = int(len(nlist) ** .5)
print(list(zip(*map(lambda c: list(filter(bool, c)) + list(filter(operator.__not__, c)), zip(*[nlist[i * size: (i + 1) * size] for i in range(size)])))))
```

This outputs:

```
[(2, 2, 4, 8), (4, 2, 8, 2), (0, 2, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Or if you prefer it flattened:

```
print([a for r in zip(*map(lambda c: list(filter(bool, c)) + list(filter(operator.__not__, c)), zip(*[nlist[i * size: (i + 1) * size] for i in range(size)]))) for a in r])
```

This outputs:

```
[2, 2, 4, 8, 4, 2, 8, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

My take on this problem:

```
from itertools import chain

nlist = [2, 2, 4, 8, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0]

def slice(l):
    for i in range(4):
        new_row = []
        for j in nlist[i::4]:
            try:
                new_row.insert(new_row.index(0), j) if j > 0 else new_row.append(j)
            except ValueError:
                new_row.insert(1, j)
        yield new_row

new_list = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*slice(nlist))))

for i in range(4):
    print(nlist[i*4:i*4+4])

print()

for i in range(4):
        print(new_list[i*4:i*4+4])

print(f'\nnew_list={new_list}')
```

Output is:

```
[2, 2, 4, 8]
[0, 2, 8, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[4, 2, 2, 0]

[2, 2, 4, 8]
[4, 2, 8, 2]
[0, 2, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]

new_list=[2, 2, 4, 8, 4, 2, 8, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way to do what you want. Note I changed the board data a little for testing purposes.

```
def vert_shift_zeros(board, width, height):
    """ Shift all the zeros to the end of each column in the board. """
    for col in range(width):
        # Get a column of data.
        column = [board[row*width + col] for row in range(height)]

        # Shift all the zeros in it to the end.
        shifted_column = [value for value in column if value]
        shifted_column.extend([0 for _ in range(height-len(shifted_column))])

        # Replace column with shifted data.
        for row in range(HEIGHT):
            board[row*width + col] = shifted_column[row]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # A non-square board for testing purposes.
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 5, 4
    nlist = [2, 2, 4, 8, -1,
             0, 2, 8, 0, -2,
             0, 0, 0, 2, -3,
             4, 2, 2, 0, -4]

    vert_shift_zeros(nlist, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    for row in range(HEIGHT):
         print(', '.join(str(value)
                for value in nlist[row*WIDTH: (row+1)*WIDTH]))
```

Output:

```
2, 2, 4, 8, -1
4, 2, 8, 2, -2
0, 2, 2, 0, -3
0, 0, 0, 0, -4
```